# Load ViewController with NavigationController ID

Tags: swift

I need help, I wanted to launch my ViewController by calling his NavigationController (with identifier only) after i successfully login.

i tried this code, but it doesn't load.

```
     let homeController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController") 
    let homeController = homeController
viewControllers = [homeController]
```

[ViewController with NavigationController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58z8m.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
let homeController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController")
```

The code above will return `UINavigationController`. You should get it's viewController by called its first children. Try this

```
// get navigation controller
let navController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationController") as! UINavigationController

// get its first child
if let homeController = navController.viewControllers.first {
    viewControllers = [homeController]
}
```

Comment: make sure your navigation controller in storyboard have id "NavigationController"